# show that $v_n \leq 2u_n$

Tags: real-analysis, definition

let $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}, \, (v_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that :

$$\forall n\geq1, \,\,\,v_n \leq \frac{u_n}{(1-u_n)^2}$$

and $u_n \to 0$, prove that for $n$ large enough we have $v_n \leq 2u_n$.

now intuitively speaking I know why this would be the case, as $(1-u_n)^2$ would be close to $1$ and thus less than $2$, but how would a formal proof of this look like ? follow up question : what is the mathematical definition of "large enough" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u_n \to 0,$ there exists $N$ such that $|u_n| \le 1/4$ for all $n \ge N.$ Then whenever $n \ge N, u_n \le 1/4 \Rightarrow (1-u_n)^2 \ge (3/4)^2 = 9/16 \Rightarrow v_n \le \frac{16}{9} u_n \le^* 2u_n.$

Large enough means exactly what I just used: A statement holds for "$n$ large enough" if there exists $N$ such that it holds for all $n \ge N.$

*The statetement you are trying to prove is false unless we assume $\{u_n\}$ is a non-negative sequence. Else, let $u_n = -1/n, v_n = \frac{u_n}{(1-u_n)^2} = -\frac{n}{(1+n)^2}.$ The inequality $v_n \le 2u_n$ transforms to $\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \ge 2,$ which is actually false for all $n.$

Answer (score 1):

We see that
\begin{align}
\frac{u_n}{(1-u_n)^2} \le u_n \left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\right)^2 \le 2u_n
\end{align}
since $u_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: ... if we assume in addition that $u_n \geq 0$.

Comment: @Rigel. Yes, I am assuming $u_n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true if $u_n>0$.

Large enough means that there exists some number $N$ such that $v_n\leq 2u_n$ for all $n\geq N$.

As you pointed out $u_n\rightarrow 0$, so consider that $u_n/(1-x)^2\leq 2u_n$ implies $1/2\leq (1-x)^2$ (notice that $u_n<0$ would have *reversed* the inequality), which holds for all $x<1-1/\sqrt{2}$. Simpler yet, it holds for all $x$ *small-enough*.

To solve this problem, since $u_n\rightarrow 0$, there's some $N>0$ such that $|u_n|\leq 1-1/\sqrt{2}$ for all $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

$u_n \to 0$ means that $ \forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ : $\forall n\geqslant N$, $|u_n-0|\leqslant \varepsilon$
$\implies (1-u_n) \geqslant 1-\varepsilon$, for all $n\geqslant N$.

then  $v_n=\dfrac{u_n}{(1-u_n)^2} \leqslant \dfrac{u_n}{(1-\varepsilon)^2}$, for $\dfrac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)^2} \leqslant 2,$ it suffies to choose $\varepsilon =1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ to get $N$ large enough.